# Dependency still on classpath after Gradle dependency exclusion

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I want to remove:

> "com.vaadin.external.google:androidjson:0.0.20131108.vaadin1"

from my classpath. With the dependency tree I saw that this dependency comes from:

> 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-rocessor:1.5.8.RELEASE'.

Therefore I changed it to the following:

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.5.8.RELEASE'){
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
}
```

My issue is that the dependency still gets pulled:

```
...
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.5.8.RELEASE
|    \--- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had this issue before where the dependency was also being brought in by a test compile dependency:     testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'}
Let me know if adding that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the Issue. How did you figure that out.
It´s interesting that this dependency was still on the classpath when running the artefact.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had a very large dependency tree and I started to narrow it down by focusing on compile then test compile with the command `gradle dependencies --configuration [compile|testCompile]`. That's when I happened to notice vaadin with the test compile dependencies. Not sure if it was on the full report though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely you have a test dependency as well that needs to be excluded. Include the following in your script:

```
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-te‌​st") { 
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json
'}
```